# react name of this <chart.component .../> type of component

Tags: reactjs

Does anyone know what is the name of this type of components?

`<chart.component data={...} type={...} />`

I mean the usages of the '.' between `chart` and `component`

`<chart.component ... />`

The keyword name could be awesome to do some googling.
Any article too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dot notation is used to represent **compound components** within React. The idea was introduced by Kent Dodds as an advanced react component pattern. In your example,`<chart.component ... />` the `.component` is a static property which has been added to the `<chart>` component.

This pattern is frequently used in the [Semantic UI React](https://react.semantic-ui.com/) library as well. For more information checkout [Kent's blog](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/compound-components-with-react-hooks) as well as this [blog article](https://www.jakewiesler.com/blog/compound-component-basics/) as they get into more specific use cases and examples of this pattern.

Hopefully that helps!